# FCM firewall restriction

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

We are using FCM for our android app.

But our customer has a firewall restriction on their network.
They gave port (5228, 5229, 5230) permission for geting message from FCM, but we can't get token at the init state.

We connect to an other network to get token, then connect again restricted network and send notification succesfuly.

Is there an other permission have to be given for the token registration for FCM service?

Answer (score 6):

**Here's what Firebase documentation stated about [firewall and network restriction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messaging-ports-and-your-firewall):**

If your organization has a firewall to restrict traffic to or from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow mobile devices to connect with FCM in order for devices on your network to receive messages. FCM typically uses port 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230.

For outgoing connections, FCM doesn't provide specific IPs because our IP range changes too frequently and your firewall rules could get out of date impacting your users' experience. Ideally, you will whitelist ports 5228-5230 with no IP restrictions. However, if you must have an IP restriction, you should whitelist all of the IP addresses in the IPv4 and IPv6 blocks listed in Google's ASN of 15169. This is a large list and you should plan to update your rules monthly. Problems caused by firewall IP restrictions are often intermittent and difficult to diagnose.

**Ports to open for incoming messages:**

> - 5228
> - 5229
> - 5230

**Ports to allow outgoing connections:**

> One of these (option #1 is preferred):
>
> - No IP restrictions
> - All IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed
>   in [Google's ASN of 15169](https://ipinfo.io/AS15169). Don't forget to update this at least once a
>   month.

**Network Address Translation and/or Stateful Packet Inspection firewalls:**

If your network implements Network Address Translation (NAT) or Stateful Packet Inspection (SPI), implement a 30 minute or larger timeout for our connections over ports 5228-5230. This enables us to provide reliable connectivity while reducing the battery consumption of your users' mobile devices.

Comment: There's an edit suggesting adding 443 to the list. The documentation you're quoting does have that number but while the page states it was *Last updated 2020-07-10 UTC*, it doesn't say when that specific edit was made. It would be useful to note when the change was made/what versions it's valid for if you approve the edit.